# How to serve nodejs app using distroless image in Dockerfile?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am trying to build this example into a distroless image: https://github.com/docker-hy/frontend-example-docker

Using vanilla image it would build and run like following:

```
FROM node:10

COPY . .  

RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The following won't work because npm isn't there!

```
FROM node:10 AS builder
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install

FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:10
COPY --from=builder /app /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How do I use distroless images to serve apps like the above example?

Answer (score 3):

The Google documentation seems pretty clear on this, you could just copy/paste their Dockerfile from https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/examples/nodejs/Dockerfile

The relevant bit though is this being the 'second stage' - note no NPM command!

```
FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:10
COPY --from=build-env /app /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["hello.js"]
```

Further, as [docs](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/tree/master/nodejs#usage) for that specific image on say, the ENTRYPOINT is defined as 'node' for this image, so you should be passing effectively whatever script your 'npm run start' command is calling to kick off.

Comment: Yes but the app I am trying to build doesn't have 'hello.js', it's served with "webpack --mode production && serve -s -l 5000 dist" do I need to change the source code? Thanks for help

Comment: Without knowing your app's actual code, it's hard to say what exactly you need to do except I will not that it looks like every time you start the app, you are building - which is not ideal. You should be effectively doing the `webpack` step in the builder, then the `serve` on your actual final image. What that `serve` should translate to i'm not sure though

Comment: Your `webpack --mode production` will (if configured correctly) generate a couple of files that need to be shipped. If you want to serve these static files via a node server (like express), you'll need an additional script that starts your server.